# How to limit the buffer pool in Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

How do I limit the buffer pool in Microsoft SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Was it too difficult for you to find query hot to limit buffer pool. Point here is limiting buffer pool is easy trick lies with putting appropriate value for max server memory hope you have one. Plus please do a bit of search before posting if you could not find answer you can post

Answer (score 1):

You can set "max server memory" using following code.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'max server memory', 4096;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Comment: How do I run the code?

Comment: You run this in your master database.  Change that figure of 4096.  That is just an example.  Do you know how much memory the host has and how much (max) you want to allocate to sql server? If yes put that figure in MB.

Comment: @Ewe...Is this machine dedicated to SQL server ? Does it has multiple instances. Do you use SSIS/RS/AS how much is total RAM. Please give complete information then only I can give you answer –